# User is not Verifying, while login in Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Hello I am new to reacts. I am implementing reactJs Login system. I want to verify my user from backend(MongoDb) then to show User Dashboard. I tried some similar problems but didn't get my solution

**What is Problem**

*Whenever i am trying to login, by giving username and password, it redirects to user dashboard. By giving wrong email or password also it goes to user dashboard*

**what i Tried**

*I tried all the logic behind but the problem is same*

**Login.jsx(react)**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import zerotwo from "../images/02.svg"
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const Login = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const [detail, setDetail] = useState({  
        email: "",  
        password: "",
    })

    let name, value
    const handleInput = (e) => {
        name = e.target.name
        value = e.target.value
        setDetail({ ...detail, [name]: value })
    }

    const PostData = async (e) => {
        
        e.preventDefault()
        const {  email, password } = detail
        
        const res = await fetch("/login", {
            
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({
                 email, password
            })
        })

        const data = await res.json()
        

        if (data === 400 || !data) {
            alert("not registered")
            navigate('/')
        } else {
            alert("Sucesssfuly")
            navigate('/dashboard')
        }
    }
```

**app.js(backend)**

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    let token
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body
        if (!email || !password) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "fill the credentials" })
        }

        const UserLogin = await User.findOne({ email: email })

        if (UserLogin) {

            const passmatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, UserLogin.password)

            token = await UserLogin.generateAuthToken()
            // console.log(token);
            res.cookie("jwt",token,{
                expires : new Date(Date.now()+25892000000),
                httpOnly : true
            })

            if (!passmatch) {
                res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" })
            }
            else {
                res.status(200).json({ message: "sign in successfully" })
            }
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" })
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

I tried all logics behind in verifying username and password.
I am expecting to verify user properly by his/her username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking `data` object on status code here - `data === 400`, but it will never be true, cause you returning object `{ error: "Invalid credentials" }` if creds are invalid.
You probably wanted to check the response status code, so it should be

```
if (res.status === 400)
```

Also, side note - I would recommend to return `401` status code for Authentication error (wrong password), it specifically designed for such cases and it is standard. `400` in this case could be if for example empty `username` or `password` were provided - that would make sense, cause `400` error is more for validation.